# what is the difference between items = [] and map = {}?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between those variables in jQuery ?

```js
 items = [];
 map = {};
```

Comment: `[]` is an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), `{}` is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: many thanks for your support